# Redirect the page to users from another country/ Region using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api, user

we require to redirect the users of other country/region for one of the pages in sharepoint online site.

how can we check we the logged in user belong to specific country/region?

what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Put the user's region in a user profile property. Do a GET request for the property and redirect as needed.

Alternate approach, put the users in an AD group. Put the AD group in a SharePoint group. Check if the current user is in that group, and do the redirection if true.